# Rank Based on two tables

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I need some help to calculate the rank from two table.

Suppose i have two table - table1 and table2.

In table1, i have below info

```
Disease value
A       20
B       10
C       35
```

In table2, i have below info

```
Diseaselist  Othervalue
A             20
B             10
D             35
E             20
```

I want to check here, if A from table1 is available in table 2 then it will get high rank othewise less rank. Here C in table1 has more value than A but it is not available in table2 so it will get less rank than A and B.

Kindly sugges how would i accomplish this.

Regards,
Ratan

Answer (score 1):

You can join the two tables using `LEFT JOIN`. And to order the rows, use `CASE` statement.

```
SELECT  a.Disease, a.Value
FROM    Table1 a
        LEFT JOIN Table2 b
            ON a.Disease = b.DiseaseList
ORDER   BY CASE WHEN b.DiseaseList IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END, 
           a.Value DESC
```

Comment: Hi John,Thank you for the help. I also want member from table2, I am trying to use full outer join but its giving me null. Regards,Ratan